# How to find maximum value in a column of an Excel sheet using java?

Tags: java, excel, jxl

[The image displays my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MsxH.png)

I want to find the maximum value in the first column, but the code below shows an error.

> Bus1.java:52: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>='
>                           if(numbusarray.get(row)>=max);
>                                                  ^   first type:  String   second type: int Bus1.java:53: error: incompatible types: String
>   cannot be converted to int
>                           max=numbusarray.get(row);

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Bus1{

List<String> numbusarray = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> numcommutersarray = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> numcommercialarray = new ArrayList<String>();

public void readExcel() throws BiffException, IOException//method to read       contents form excel
{
    String FilePath = "Bus1.xls";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max=0;

    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Bus1");// TO get the access to the sheet
    int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();// To get the number of rows present in  sheet
    int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();// To get the number of columns present in sheet

    //adding excel contents from every column to arraylist

    for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++)
    {
        numcommutersarray.add(sh.getCell(3, row).getContents());
    }

    for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++)
    {
        numcommercialarray.add(sh.getCell(5, row).getContents());
    }

    for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++)
    {
        if(numbusarray.get(row)>=max);
        max=numbusarray.get(row);

    }
    System.out.println(max);

    Iterator itr=numbusarray.iterator(); //to print arraylist demo 
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
        System.out.println(itr.next());  
    }
    }//end of method to read contents from excel

    public static void main(String args[]) throws BiffException, IOException  //main class
    {
        Bus1 DT = new Bus1();
        DT.readExcel();
    }//end of main class

}
```

Comment: You're trying to compare strings (from `numbusarray.get(row)`) with an number (`max`) in the first error. In the second error you're trying to set a number equal to a string. To solve this use; `Double.parseDouble(numbusarray.get(row))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The code has compiled but the following run time error is displayed,                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size:
0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at Bus1.readExcel(Bus1.java:42)
        at Bus1.main(Bus1.java:57)

Comment: rectified the code....no more errors....thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **numbusarray** contains strings and you are trying to compare **string** with **int**. You should first convert to int like this:

```
int intNumber = Integer.parseInt(YourString);
```

And always make sure your String can be converted to int otherwise it will raise a **NumberFormatException**, you can also output your **numbusarray** contents to check.

Although sometimes Java can help you convert types but for beginners it's better to explicitly convert types and I believe this will save you a lot of time.

For adding things to **List**, you should put the appropriate type objects into it. That's what your

```
List<String> numcommutersarray
```

wants, it contains the **String** type objects.

Comment: The code has compiled but the following run time error is displayed, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653) at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429) at Bus1.readExcel(Bus1.java:42) at Bus1.main(Bus1.java:57)

Comment: I added the following changes as suggested,                                        for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++)
    {
        if(Integer.parseInt(numbusarray.get(row))>=max);
        max=Integer.parseInt(numbusarray.get(row));

    }
    System.out.println(max);